# LayoutDocument hide header tabs in DockingManager.DocumentPaneControlStyle

Tags: wpf, xaml, avalondock

I'm using Avalondock 2 and need to hide the TabItem of a `LayoutDocument`. I know that there was a function back in Avalondock 1.3 which seems to be gone in 2.0.

I've tried to change the template of the `LayoutDocumentPaneControl` and want to know if it's possible to change a single Property without a complete redesign of the template. Here's what I i want to achive.

```
<xcad:DockingManager.DocumentPaneControlStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneControl}">
                    <xcad:DocumentPaneTabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </Style>
</xcad:DockingManager.DocumentPaneControlStyle>
```

That part hides the Header as I want, but of course everything else too.

So is there a way to hide the `DocumentPaneTabPanel` with a `BasedOn` or something?

TL;DR

Is there a way to hide the `DocumentPaneTabPanel` in Avalondock 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other way unfortunately. I used the AvalonDock 2.0 found here: https://avalondock.codeplex.com/

There doesn't seem to be any property exposed to control the `Visibility` of the `DocumentPaneTabPanel` in the `ControlTemplate`.
If you check the default `Style` used for the `LayoutDocumentPaneControl` [here](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Version2.0/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock/Themes/generic.xaml) you can see that there is no `TemplateBinding` or any `DataTrigger` affecting the `DocumentPaneTabPanel` named `HeaderPanel` so I don't see a way of changing it without modifying the `ControlTemplate.`

You should create a `DockingManagerStyles.xaml` `ResourceDictionary` and put this in there:

```
<xcad:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
<xcad:ActivateCommandLayoutItemFromLayoutModelConverter x:Key="ActivateCommandLayoutItemFromLayoutModelConverter"/>

<Style x:Key="TablessDocumentPaneControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneControl}">
                <Grid ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!--Following border is required to catch mouse events-->
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    <Grid  Panel.ZIndex="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <xcad:DocumentPaneTabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <xcad:DropDownButton x:Name="MenuDropDownButton" 
                                                Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}" 
                                                Focusable="False" Grid.Column="1">
                            <xcad:DropDownButton.DropDownContextMenu>
                                <xcad:ContextMenuEx
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Model.ChildrenSorted, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <xcad:ContextMenuEx.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:MenuItemEx}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
                                            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{Binding Path=Root.Manager.DocumentPaneMenuItemHeaderTemplate}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplateSelector" Value="{Binding Path=Root.Manager.DocumentPaneMenuItemHeaderTemplateSelector}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="IconTemplate" Value="{Binding Path=Root.Manager.IconContentTemplate}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="IconTemplateSelector" Value="{Binding Path=Root.Manager.IconContentTemplateSelector}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ActivateCommandLayoutItemFromLayoutModelConverter}}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </xcad:ContextMenuEx.ItemContainerStyle>
                                </xcad:ContextMenuEx>
                            </xcad:DropDownButton.DropDownContextMenu>
                            <Image Source="/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;component/Themes/Generic/Images/PinDocMenu.png"/>
                        </xcad:DropDownButton>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" 
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" 
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" 
                                        ContentSource="SelectedContent" 
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Model.ChildrenCount}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="MenuDropDownButton" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <xcad:LayoutDocumentTabItem Model="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <xcad:LayoutDocumentControl Model="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then include it in the `MergedDictionaries` section of your `App.xaml` to change the tabs globally in your application.

You should be able to use it like:

```
<xcad:DockingManager DocumentPaneControlStyle="{StaticResource TablessDocumentPaneControlStyle}">
    <!-- Layout here -->
</xcad:DockingManager>
```

**Update**

In the [latest version on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xceed.Products.Wpf.Toolkit.AvalonDock/) there is a `ShowHeader` property on `LayoutDocumentPane`. So in that version you can just do:

```
<xcad:DockingManager>
    <xcad:LayoutRoot>
        <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup x:Name="leftDocumentGroup">
                        <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane ShowHeader="False">
                            <xcad:LayoutDocument Title="Left Doc"></xcad:LayoutDocument>
                        </xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                    </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                    <xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup x:Name="rightDocumentGroup">
                        <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                            <xcad:LayoutDocument Title="Right Doc"></xcad:LayoutDocument>
                        </xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                    </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                </xcad:LayoutPanel>
            </xcad:LayoutPanel>
        </xcad:LayoutPanel>
    </xcad:LayoutRoot>
</xcad:DockingManager>
```

Comment: Very good thank you. Just installed the newest Version 10min before you anwered and found the ShowHeader function myself ;)

Comment: Little question about the latest Version here. The newest version is Part of the Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit Plus isn't it?

Comment: Avalon dock in the 3.0.0 version of the Extended WPF Tool kit also have the "ShowHeader" property: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/